# jQuery.mmenu vertical dropdowns for 3rd level items

Tags: jquery, html, css, mmenu

What would be the best way to change the 3rd level navigation items from being horizontal (sliding) to open vertically right below the clicked menu item?

Mobile menu HTML structure:

```
<div id="mobile-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><span>Telefoni &amp; naprave</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span>Telefoni</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">NOVO:iPhone 7</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Android telefoni</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Windows telefoni</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">LTE telefoni</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sony Xperia X</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Samsung Galaxy S7</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ORTO DIL</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span>Naprave za internet</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Wi-Fi naprave</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Naprave za domači internet</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span>Tablični računalniki</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">LTE tablični računalniki</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">iPad Air 16GB</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Alcatel One Touch POP 10</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span>Dodatki za telefone</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Bluetooth slušalke</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ovitki, etuiji, zaščita</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Avto oprema</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Baterije in polnilci</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Spominske kartice</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Zvočniki in ostali dodatki</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Omrežje</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Paketi &amp; storitve</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our address</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Internet &amp; omrežje</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span>Mobilni internet za računalnik in tablico</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Napravo že imam</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kupiti želim novo napravo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Paket 2. SIM</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span>Mobilni internet za telefon</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Z naročnino</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Brez naročnino</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span>Domači internet</span></li>
                <li><span>Vikend internet</span></li>
                <li><span>Neskončni internet</span></li>
                <li><span>Predplačniški SIMPLnet</span></li>
                <li><span>Akcije in uporabne informacije</span></li>
                <li><span>Omrežje</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Pomoč &amp; informacije</span></li>
        <li><span>Moj A1 (Neprijavljen)</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Current mobile menu behaviour in action:

[image: mmenu animation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to simply add a class `Vertical` to the parent `ul` for which you want to show the dropdown instead of the sliding menu.

> The classname on a submenu (a nested UL) that should expand below
>   their parent instead of slide in from the right.

See for reference http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/options/configuration.html